# R package "tree": how to control the maximum tree depth?

Tags: r, classification

The R package "tree" restricts the maximum tree depth to 31.  If the function `tree` is applied to a large dataset, this limit is easily reached:

```
> library("tree")
> library("ElemStatLearn")
> data <- list(image=as.matrix(zip.train[,-1]), digit=as.factor(zip.train[,1]))
> t <- tree(digit~image, data, split="gini")
Error in tree(digit ~ image, data, split = "gini") : 
  maximum depth reached
Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> tree -> .C
```

Is there a way to tell `tree` to just stop growing the tree when the maximum tree depth is reached, rather than aborting with an error?
(In other words: is there an equivalent for the `maxdepth` parameter of `rpart.control`?)

Comment: Take a look at `?tree` and `?tree.control` to set parameters.

Comment: I read the help pages, but didn't find a parameter for this.  Maybe I overlooked something?

Comment: Did this ever reach a resolution?

Comment: @Vincent My personal conclusion was to use "rpart" instead of "tree".

Comment: Thanks! @jochen can you be more specific what your solution was?

Comment: @Vincent tree and rpart are two competing packages which both can construct classification trees.  They do things slightly differently, and by experimenting I (or rather a student of mine) got the impression that rpart often seems more polished than tree.  So my conclusion was: stop using the tree package, start using the rpart package instead.  Docs for rpart are here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/rpart.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @jochen's suggestion that the `rpart` package seems to be more polished than the `tree` package. However, there are some little things that the `tree` package seems to be doing better. 
For example, it's much easier to draw decision boundaries for a `tree` object than it is for an `rpart` object (especially using `ggplot`). 
Regarding Vincent's question, I had some limited success controlling the depth of a `tree` tree  by using the `tree.control(min.cut=)` option as in the code below. By changing the minimum nuber of elements in a terminal node you may be able to exercise limited  control over depth.

```
library("ElemStatLearn")
 library("tree")
 data <- list(image=as.matrix(zip.train[,-1]), digit=as.factor(zip.train[,1]))
 t <- tree(digit~image, data, split="gini", control=tree.control(1866496, mincut = 1000))
 library(maptree)
 draw.tree(t)
```